# How can I find out which is the primary mouse button with the winapi?

Tags: winapi

The SwapMouseButton() API lets you switch the "primary" mouse button between the left and right mouse buttons. But is there an API for finding out what the current primary mouse button setting is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`GetSystemMetrics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) API for this with the `SM_SWAPBUTTON` value of the argument.